# Copying some columns from one table to another while also adding user input values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, Table 1 and Table 2. Table 2 contains the exact same columns as table 1 with five additional columns. Table 1 contains basic employee information, and table 2 contains a history of every time the employee is not at work.

Through a VBA built program, the user can mark an employee as absent and then supply a type of absence, an exception can be granted, and then a reason for the exception. Whenever an absence is created, I want to copy the employee info from table 1, insert it into table 2 along with the type of absence, exception, and exception reason.

I know how to copy the information from table 1 to table 2, but how can I do that and insert the new values from the user input?

```
INSERT INTO Table 2(
FirstName,
LastName,
AgentName,
Location,
EmployeeGroup,
ContractAgency,
Manager,
Supervisor,
Team,
Title,
Position,
StaffCIMID,
FTPT,
Bilingual,
Five9Email,
Email,
WeekdaySchedule,
WeekendSchedule,
CreatedBy,
CreatedDate,
ModifiedBy,
ModifiedDate,
Notseatedreason,
Exception,
Exceptionreason
)

SELECT (
FirstName,
LastName,
AgentName,
Location,
EmployeeGroup,
ContractAgency,
Manager,
Supervisor,
Team,
Title,
Position,
StaffCIMID,
FTPT,
Bilingual,
Five9Email,
Email,
WeekdaySchedule,
WeekendSchedule
)
FROM Table 1 
WHERE AgentName = 'userselectedvalue'
```

`CreatedBy,CreatedDate,Notseatedreason,Exception,Exceptionreason`
are the additional colums on Table 2 that need to be filled based on user input. Createdby just captures the AD username, createddate just grabs the system time, notseatedreason is a VBA form user input, Exception is a VBA userform bit based on a checkbox, Exceptionreason is a VBA userform input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want :

```
insert into table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, . . .)
   select col1, col2, @inputvalue1, @inputvalue2, . . .
   from table1 t1
   where . . .;
```

A `select` statement where you can define a constants, functions that can be from an operator or operators, or a `subquery`.

Comment: So I can just add the @inputvalue parameters into the select statement even though they don't exist on table1?

Comment: @Jb83 . . . Yes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. . . Thanks for typo.